# Как вернуть статус код 404 VirtualFileResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

```
        [HttpGet]
        public VirtualFileResult GetVirtualFile(string fileName)
        {
            fileName = fileName.Replace(" ", "") + ".pdf";
            var filepath = Path.Combine("~/Files", fileName);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                return ;
            }
            return File(filepath, "application/pdf", fileName);
        }
```

Если файл не существует, то добавить логику, которая будет возвращать страницу со статус-кодом 404

Comment: return NotFound();

Comment: @Konst пишет ошибку Cannot convert expression type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundResult' to return type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.VirtualFileResult. Можно поменять на IActionResult не будет ошибкой ?

Answer (score 1):

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetVirtualFile(string fileName)
        {
            fileName = fileName.Replace(" ", "") + ".pdf";
            var filePath = Path.Combine("~/Files", fileName);
            try
            {
                return PhysicalFile(filePath, "application/pdf", fileName);
            }

            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

Comment: А если между проверкой наличия файла и фактом начала отдачи файла он будет удален? метод упадет.

Comment: @aepot ну об этом я не думал если честно. Мне на данный момент проверка на то что файл существует нужна была

Comment: попробуйте между проверкой и отдачей для теста поставить большую паузу, и удалить руками файл во время нее, увидите, что произойдет.

Comment: @aepot FileNotFoundException: Could not find file  вышло

Comment: @aepot получается надо все в try catch поместить? Чтобы в процессе не получить ошибку

Comment: Ну вот, о чем я и говорил, используйте `try { return File(filepath, "application/pdf", fileName); } catch (FileNotFoundException) { return NotFound(); } catch (Exception) { return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError); }`

Comment: @aepot Теперь понял, спасибо большое

Comment: Можете по типам исключений разные HTTP ошибки возвращать.

Comment: @aepot хорошо, благодарю

Comment: настройте логирование исключений, чем больше будет сервак - тем сложнее будет понять, где поломалось. NotFound например можно не логировать, а вот все остальное - вполне.